# Will the heat from the external hard disk cause any problems if I have the hard disk wrapped in the plasic?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I don't like to bother myself with cleaning my stuff (i'm really lazy) but I don't like my stuff to be dirty as well. So basically I don't remove the plastic of  my external hard disk even when its plugged into the laptop (and rather hot I think, relatively).

[image]

I'm wondering will the heat cause any unforesee problems ?

Comment: No, it will not cause any unforeseen problems... it will cause problems that *have been* foreseen. Even you yourself already predict problems ;-)

Comment: How is this not a real question?

Comment: @Sathya why is this closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Don't avoid cleaning.

*I'd find it demeaning to be cleaning toilets.* ~ [Jack Kevorkian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Kevorkian)

> I don't like to bother myself with cleaning my stuff (i'm really lazy)

Things will get (really) dirty after a while; in the end you will have to, if you **don't want to get sick**...

> but I don't like my stuff to be dirty as well.

There aren't really other solutions than cleaning or getting someone to  build you a [cleanroom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleanroom).

You don't have to clean everything at once, start with a *single thing*. Like a corner of your desk or room...

> So basically I don't remove the plastic of my external hard disk even when its plugged into the laptop (and rather hot I think, relatively).

The external hard disk is normally close to air tight and even if dust gets into it it won't cause problems. Please note, the plastic will get dirty instead of your hard disk as the plastic doesn't magically make the dust disappear; it will just be on the plastic or the table instead!

> I'm wondering will the heat cause any unforesee problems ?

Yes, you are doing more worse than good by preventing air circulation and introducing overheating...

---

## Do get rid of the dirt.

*I came from a dirt farm, now I'm filthy rich.* ~ [Larry Holmes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Holmes)

Here are some pictures that make it clear why cleaning *just once in a long while* does help...

[image]

You should rather worry what your fingers touch than the effects of a plastic bag.

[image]

Yes, the keyboard your using now is most likely more dirty than a toilet seat.

Sources: [Dr. Charles Gerba from the university of Arizona](http://www.infectioncontroltoday.com/news/2007/02/germs-working-overtime-especially-at-women-s-desk.aspx) as well as a [swab test by a U.K. microbiologist](http://abcnews.go.com/Health/Germs/story?id=4774746&page=1).

[image]

This happens when you don't clean; now, where would the grease and dirt come from?

Answer (score 10):

You seem to be needlessly worried about the hard drive getting dirty.  Why would it get any dirtier than your laptop?

In any case, I do think it's a bad idea to keep it in plastic.  It will clear not benefit from circulating air, which is the main way the unit will stay cool(er).

I recommend you take it out of the bag.

Comment: No unforseen problems - but one BIG seeable one: overheating! Free the drive and let it breathe/cool before it dies an early death.

Comment: +1 for "needlessly worried about the hard drive getting dirty".